# What is significance of Kaabah besides a place for doing worship?

Tags: kaabah

Some muslims believe that our feet should not be towards Kaabah because it is disrespectful. But if Kaabah is just a building where we go for worship then how can we disrespect a building? Unless of course there is hadith or verse of Quran telling us to associate love and respect with Kaabah.

Therefore my question is:

**What is significance of Kaabah besides a place for doing worship? Are we supposed to love and respect the building? Will that give us sawab?**

**Note**: My question is not about pointing feet at Kabah in particular. It is about Whether we need to love and respect the building itself or not.

Please cite your answer from Quran or Hadith or scholarly opinion.

PS: I do know that Quran has verses that require us to adhere to certain rules while we're inside Kaabah because it is a place of worship.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: In the name of Allah, the most Beneficent, most Merciful]

Contradictory to what you say, **Ka'bah** is not a mere building, it is a house of worship. Rather, it is the first ever place of worship the mankind was allotted.

> Indeed, the first House [of worship] established for mankind was that at Makkah - blessed and a guidance for the worlds. [***Qur'an 3:96.***](http://quran.com/3/96)

Most importantly, Allah has called it **"My House"** in the following Ayah and maybe a few more Ayaah.

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when We designated for Abraham the site of the House, [saying], "Do not associate anything with Me and purify My House for those who perform Tawaf and those who stand [in prayer] and those who bow and prostrate. [***Qur'an 22:26***](http://quran.com/22/26)

Though Allah does not dwell in that house, nor does he need a house, he has still called it as **"My House"** (Allah's house or Baythullah). This signifies its importance and sacredness. And we have no right to call it a mere building.

The [most important significance of Ka'bah is to unify the people.](http://www.icbwayland.org/outreach/kaaba.html). If there was no Qibla, muslims would pray facing anywhere and they would consider any place they personally respect as their Qibla. Like the muslims are now divided on other bases, they would have been divided based on Qibla.

After realising its importance, if a person still finds no harm in just pointing the feet toward the Ka'bah it should be acceptable because there is no hadith or Ayah supporting that it is Haraam or makrooh. When Qur'an and Hadith don't support or contradict an act, we are left with Ijmaa'. When we consider Ijmaa', some scholars like Mufti Ibraheem Desai find it disrespectful, [some](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/12871)  don't. It's up to your heart now. If a person's heart is very rational and finds no harm, its up to him. But, if his heart considers it disrespectful, and he still points it purposely, he is a transgressor.

**What is significance of Kaabah besides a place for doing worship?**

1. It unites people toward one Allah whether black or white, slaves or masters, rich or poor, young or old.
2. It signifies equality in the eyes of Allah as all face toward one Qibla no matter where a person hails from, what his caste or profession or income is.
3. Further reading: [Significance of the Ka'bah.](http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-about-hajj-and-umrah/fiqh/hajj-merits-and-rulings/179128.html?Rulings=)

**Are we supposed to love and respect the building?**

When Allah has called it "My House" despite of the fact that he doesn't need a house, it is clear that he has stressed its importance. If you love and respect Allah, you must love and respect what he emphasizes.

**Will that give us sawab?**

Loving what Allah emphasizes is a consequence of loving Allah Himself. Allah loves who love Him unconditionally.

When Allah loves you, the whole heaven loves you:

> **Narrated Abu Huraira:** 
>   The Prophet said, "If Allah loves a person, He calls Gabriel saying: 'Allah loves so and so; O Gabriel, love him.' Gabriel would love him, and then Gabriel would make an announcement among the residents of the Heaven, 'Allah loves so-and-so, therefore, you should love him also.' So, all the residents of the Heavens would love him and then he is granted the pleasure of the people of the earth." ***Sahih Al-Bukhari Volume 8: Book 73: Number 66.***

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللهُمَّ علِّمنا مَا يَنْفَعُنا وَانْفَعْنا بِما عَلَّمتَنَا وزِدْنَا عِلما

Comment: @TabrezAhmed: A nice answer. I would suggest an update to include [this Ayah](http://quran.com/22/32), it's very helpful I think :)

Comment: @Mr.TAMER, when you see [this](http://www.archive.org/download/InTheShadeOfTheQuranSayyidQutb/Volume_12_surahs_21-25.pdf) tafseer,  it says the symbols "in this instance, refers to the animals sacrificed as part of the pilgrimage rituals."  and when you see [this](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2505&Itemid=77) tafseer, it considers the Sha`a'ir as the commands previously mentioned in this Surah. If it had referred to anything like a mosque, flag, or the Ka'bah, I would add it. But the Ayah you referred has different context, I suppose. Plz correct me if wrong

Answer (score 0):

> Some Muslims believe that our feet should not be towards Kabbah because it is disrespectful.

Yes, Though it is considered disrespectful , it is NOT. In the olden days (during the prophets time ) there were no loud speakers. The people used to say the azan by standing on the kaabah. So just pointing the feet towards it is insignificant. Actually it depends on your mentality - If you consider pointing your feet at anything as disrespect then don't do it & if you don't consider pointing your feet at anything as disrespect then there is no harm in doing it.

> What is significance of Kabbah besides a place for doing worship?

The main significance of the kaabah is to unify the muslims to pray in a definite direction. Nothing apart from that.

Comment: @HasanKhan i never said dont do it

Comment: @HasanKhan i said "that depends on your thinking"

Comment: Nothing apart from that? Or nothing else you know of.